# Receber dados em uma matriz c#

Tags: c#, .net, matriz

Olá,

Estava testando código pra aprender a mexer com a matriz, mas não estou conseguindo armazenar números quebrados na variável.

ele da erro de `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` e não consigo solucionar.

alguém poderia me dar uma luz.

```
    {
        Boolean stop = true;
            int x = 0;
            double[] dados = new double[x];
        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero");
            dados[x] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            x += 1;
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
            {
                stop = false;
            }
        } while (stop);

        Console.WriteLine("Dados recebidos");
        for(int i = 0; i < dados.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dados[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: só um comentário, não é estrano começar o código com uma varíavel `stop = true`? já começa parando? e `while (stop)` também é estranho... se a variável se chamasse `continuar` ou algo semelhante (não pode ser `continue`) seria melhor

Comment: x = 0 ou seja o seu array não tem posição ou posições? Como você vai guardar valores sem espaço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gustavo,

Em seu código, você cria um array com o tamanho de x, que no caso é zero:

```
int x = 0;
double[] dados = new double[x];
```

Com isso, você tem um array de tamanho zero, portanto ao tentar acessar o índice do mesmo:

```
dados[x] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Você tem o erro que de *System.IndexOutOfRangeException*

---

Você pode mudar o código para ter um array de tamanho fixo, atribuindo um tamanho para o array:

```
double[] dados = new double[10]; //Agora o array tem o tamanho de dez
```

E na condição do while, ter uma nova verificação, para evitar digitar mais que o array suporta, um exemplo seria assim:

```
if (x < dados.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite Y para continuar digitando valores:");

    if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y || x >= dados.Length)
    {
        stop = false;
    }
}
else
{
    stop = false;
}
```

No final, seu código estaria mais ou menos assim:

```
using System;

class ArrayTeste {
  static void Main()
  {
    Boolean stop = true;
    int x = 0;
    double[] dados = new double[3];

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nDigite um numero:");
        dados[x] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        x += 1;

        if (x < dados.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite Y para continuar digitando valores:");

            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
            {
                stop = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stop = false;
        }
    } while (stop);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDados recebidos");

    for(int i = 0; i < dados.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dados[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

> Obs.: O do/while seria facilmente trocado por um FOR, já que você
>   sabe qual o tamanho do array.

---

Talvez, você se interesse por listas, veja seu código utilizando de lista, fica bem mais simples... E com foreach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ListTeste {
  static void Main()
  {
    Boolean stop = true;
    List<double> dados = new List<double>();

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nDigite um numero:");
        dados.Add(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.WriteLine("Digite Y para continuar digitando valores:");

        if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
        {
            stop = false;
        }
    } while (stop);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDados recebidos");

    foreach(double valor in dados)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(valor);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

A lista não tem um tamanho pré-definido, então eu posso manter o while enquanto tiver paciência de digitar números.

---

Por fim, você pode criar a matriz com base em um número informado:

```
int tamanho = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double[] dados = new double[tamanho];
Console.WriteLine(dados.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que estará a utilizar `Array` para algum tipo de trabalho acadêmico, por isso o uso de `List` deverá estar fora de questão. É possível sim redimensionar um `Array`, algo que até é bastante simples e direto utilizando o `Array.Resize` ([Array.Resize(T[], Int32) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.8)).

Utilizando o seu código base, ficaria dessa forma:

```
int x = 0;
double[] dados = new double[1];

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero");
    dados[x] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    x++;

    if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
        break;

    Array.Resize(ref dados, x + 1);
} while (true);

Console.WriteLine("Dados recebidos");

for (int i = 0; i < dados.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dados[i]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Queria entender o voto negativo, será que é por causa do List e parte Academia ou Array.resize? Fiquei curioso

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu queria também entender, mas como ambos sabemos há imensos users que negativam respostas mas que, infelizmente, não justificam.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic nem um motivo e nem outro. Eu cliquei errado mesmo, era para ser um positivo. João Martins, por favor, edite a pergunta para eu reparar o meu erro.

Comment: @AugustoVasques por isso da minha pergunta eu achei estranho o voto ... mas, pode claro ser revertido e bom lembrar sempre ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tem como reverter sem o AR editar a resposta?

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas, parece que sim dá um tentada agora eu fiz uma edição @AugustoVasques

Comment: @VirgilioNovic deu certo. Obrigado! João Martins desculpe o transtorno.